# How to bind a custom function when the typeahead suggestion is selected/autocomplete with tab key?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead

I'm using this jQuery plugin [typeahead-addresspicker](https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker), allowing to get suggestion from Google, as showed in [this demo](http://sgruhier.github.io/typeahead-addresspicker/). (I'm using the plugin without a map displayed)

When the user select an element from the suggested list of results, I'm successfully using the event of the plugin.

But I didn't managed to bind a custom function when the user select the suggested ("typeaheaded") entry with <kbd>Tab</kbd>. (The whole point of using a typeahead version of the plugin)

> Update: in (2), I've managed to get the correct event fired, but not
>   the correct result, see at the end.

Here is what I've tried:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exemple</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" id="address" />
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="typeahead-addresspicker.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                var addressPicker = new AddressPicker();
                $('#address').typeahead({
                    highlight: true
                }, {
                    displayKey: 'description',
                    source: addressPicker.ttAdapter()
                });

                //Works, planned in the plugin
                $(addressPicker).on('addresspicker:selected', function (event, result) {
                    setResults(result);
                });

                //Doesn't work
                $(addressPicker).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, result) {
                    setResults(result);
                });

                //(1) Doesn't work too
                $(addressPicker).on('typeahead:autocomplete', function (event, result) {
                    setResults(result);
                });


                $('#address').on('typeahead:autocomplete', function (event, result) {
                    setResults(result);
                });

                //(2) This almost works, I've got the event fired, but no luck running correctly setResult with it
                function setResults(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    var premise = result.nameForType("premise"); //(3)
                    console.log(premise);
                }
            }
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

(1) Looking directly the [typeahead.js doc](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) and experimenting with [their demo page](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), when I add the following code via the console:

```
$('#demo-input').on('typeahead:autocomplete', function(ev, suggestion) {
  console.log('autocomplete : ' + suggestion);
});
```

I successfully managed to capture the event on the autocomplete of the suggestion via <kbd>Tab</kbd>, without having to intercept it from the key down event.

<s>Now I just have to make it work for the [typeahead-addresspicker](https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker)...</s>

---

(2) While the event is corretly fired, the result returned isn't the same as with the `addresspicker:selected` event, and the lien(3) return this error:

> TypeError: result.nameForType is not a function

I know the type of object returned by the `typeahed:autocomplete` event isn't the one expected, provoquing the error.

I'm now searching how to get the correct object type and how to pass it to `addressPicker`.

Comment: Is there a reason you are binding the listener to the addressPicker and not to the document?  The addressPicker won't "hear" a `typeahead:selected` event, or a `typeahead:autocomplete` event.  But the document will.

Comment: Nope, just an error/misunderstanding of mine... Let me try your suggestion, I'll come back to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working by adding this code, normally made to update the map, but even if I use the address picker without map, it made the correct event firing with the correct result type:

```
$('#address').bind("typeahead:autocompleted", addressPicker.updateMap);
```

If anyone has a proper method to achieve the same result, I'll take it!

Comment: event binding seems like the proper method to me! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to move your binding to the document (or really any element higher than the addressPicker), then you will be able to catch the typeahead events as well.

These should all still work:

```
$(document).on('addresspicker:selected', function (event, result) { setResults(result);});

$(document).on('typeahead:selected', function (event, result) { setResults(result); });

$(document).on('typeahead:autocomplete', function (event, result) { setResults(result); });
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but it didn't worked. Even the first one, replacing the working `$(addressPicker).on('addresspicker:selected', function (event, result) { setResults(result);});` by `$(document).on('addresspicker:selected', function (event, result) { setResults(result);});` fails, unfortunatelly.

Comment: I'll have to take a closer look at the github for addresspicker, because the behavior doesn't seem consistent with the default typeahead behavior.